# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input -- inside PHP with onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

getReport.php

```
<?php 
    $data = $_POST;
        //print_r($_POST);
    if (isset($_POST['idws']))
    {   
            $getListData = new getListData();
            $List = $getListData->get($_POST['idws']);
            print_r($List);
    }
    else{
        exit;
    }
    class getListData {
        public function get($idws){
            include __DIR__ .'/../../../include/conn.php';
            $q = "SELECT * from customers where idws= '$idws'
            ORDER BY idws DESC";
            $stmt = mysql_query($q);
            $id = array();
            $outp = '';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)){
                if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
                $outp .= '{"item_d":"'.rawurlencode($row['item_desc']).'",';
                $outp .= '"qty":"'. rawurlencode($row["qty"]). '"}';    
            }
            $result = '{ "status":"ok", "message":"1", "records":['.$outp.']}';
            return $result;
        }
    }

    ?>
```

I'm using a HTML tag inside PHP with onclick, and I am confused when I get the end of input error.

```
echo "<td><div style='cursor:pointer; color:#3386FF' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.detmatstat' onclick='getReport("."'".$data['id']."'".")'>$data[id]</div></td>";
```

I guess it is because the parentheses inside the `getReport`. So I tried to switch the quotation mark position, from this:

```
onclick='getReport("."'".$data['id']."'".")'
```

to this:

```
onclick='getReport(".'"'.$data['id'].'"'.")'
```

But I get this Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getReport is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick
```

Honestly, I'm still confused how to read the correct tag with so many quotation mark. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Does the `getReport` javascript function exist? Because the error is saying it doesn't, at least not at the time of this call

Comment: ... and `getReport` is in the global scope?

Comment: @zanderwar `getReport` error which it doesn't exist because I switched the single and double quotation mark. which is not correct. when I undo it, I get the end of input error.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/542a52dc873944a7c0e1d8ba61c48014cf47f415

Comment: FWIW, numbers don't need to be encapsulated with quotes

Comment: @zanderwar I executed your code, I got the `getReport is not defined` error again. in the getReport there are strings too, not only numbers.

Comment: Then you have your answer, `getReport` does not exist, or is not in the global scope. Numerical-only values do not need to be encapsulated with quotes within function parameters, but CAN BE without harm. We can't help you beyond making you realise the function you're asking for does not exist

Comment: @zanderwar please see my updated question..

Comment: @danielpr the answer remains, if the console is saying getReport is not defined, then getReport is not defined. At least not in the place you're trying to access it

Comment: @danielpr If you don't sure if the getReport function is in the scope or not right click on page and click on view source find the .js file you have written code for getReprot (var) function. 

More you need to check your html you have written in php. I guess you should make changes like: 


echo "<td><div style='cursor:pointer; color:#3386FF' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.detmatstat' onclick='getReport(".$data['id'].")'>$data['id']</div></td>";

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
<?php echo "<div style='cursor:pointer; color:#3386FF' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.detmatstat' onclick='getReport(".$data[id].")'>".$data[id]."</div>";
 ?>
```